# SQL query not working for changing null values

Tags: sql, null, ms-access-2007

I have a database table with over 18,000 rows in Access 2007.

I am trying to create a primary key but I have too many null values. Therefore, I would like to replace those null values with actual values. To do so, I wrote the following SQL statement:

```sql
UPDATE [File]
SET [Date] = '01/01/1000'
WHERE [Date] = NULL;
```

Unfortunately, this `UPDATE` statement is not working (none of the null values are changing). Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because nothing = NULL. You need to change this to use IS NULL. You also should use the ANSI dateformat.

```
UPDATE [File]
SET [Date] = '1000-01-01'
WHERE [Date] IS NULL;
```

This date is not valid in many DBMS. In sql server this would have to be a datetime2. I don't know about mysql or Access.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to replace the `=` with `IS` and see if it fixes the issue

```
UPDATE [File]
SET [Date] = '01/01/1000'
WHERE [Date] IS NULL;
```

PS: Depending on your DBMS / configuration, '01/01/1000' could be a problem